# Can you delay 0x80070035 "The network path was not found" in Win11?

Tags: networking, windows-11

I have an NAS that's in sleep most of the time. So when I want to connect via windows explorer, it needs some seconds to wake up.
In Win7 and 10, that was no problem. Since I updated all my machines to W11, I get Error 0x80070035 "The network path was not found" every time I want to connect, because the NAS is still waking up. I close the error, try again, it works, instantly.

Is there a way I can lengthen the time before Win11 throws the error? Some registry entry?

Comment: Make a batch file:    Net Use   ;  pause ; Connect drive.